# Determine if data is related in R

Tags: r, statistics, comparison

I have two data sets and I would like to see if there is a relationship between them.

The first data set contains the money spent on advertising for a health campaign, whilst the second contains the number of casualties over the same period of time. I would like to see if spending more money implies less casualties. What is the best way to compare the two?

Regarding the dataset, both contain a date and a value.

Comment: What have you tried already?  What is it that you can't figure out on your own with textbooks, Google, and the search bar above?

Comment: Just enter your casualty data [into Google correlate](https://www.google.com/trends/correlate#) and you can see all sorts of variables that correlate with casualties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that

```
set.seed(44) 
deaths<- 10:1 + sample.int(3, 10, replace = T)
```

and

```
spent<- seq(100, 550, by = 50 )
```

The very first thing you want to do when you get your data is literally to look at it. This can be done relatively painlessly with

```
plot(spent, deaths)
```

which yields

[image]

So it looks like the more we spend, the less deaths there are. That makes sense. But how can we quantify that statement. Using `cor()` will give us the correlation between the two variables `spent` and `deaths`.

```
cor(spent, deaths)
# [1] -0.9809581
```

So it looks like they are very strong (and negatively correlated.) One other simple method (that is closely related to `cor()`) is to fit a linear model.

```
model<- lm(deaths~spent)
```

The `summary()` call yields a lot of useful information about the model you just fit, the interpretation of which is beyond the scope of this post, but can be readily found with some quick Googling.

```
summary(model) 

#Call:
#lm(formula = deaths ~ spent)

#Residuals:
# Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-0.89697 -0.51515 -0.05758  0.46364  1.01818 

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) 14.151515   0.539649   26.22 4.80e-09 ***
#spent       -0.021697   0.001519  -14.29 5.62e-07 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 0.6898 on 8 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9623,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9576 
#F-statistic: 204.1 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 5.622e-07
```